# React native gradle build error -> temporary workspace copy error

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

I am currently trying to test out google login with expo, and I am facing the following error when using `expo run:android`

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':gradle-plugin'.
 Multiple build operations failed.
  Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\04b2391c437efaa204e156de4d548a2b-cda26d44-b981-4798-8f46-71509d888824) to immutable location (C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\04b2391c437efaa204e156de4d548a2b)
```

there are multiple such failed move operations. I tried stopping gradle and deleting the cache, it still did not work. I have tried running the command as admin still no go. I ran `gradlew --stacktrace` this is what I got but cannot understand what that means

```
     * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':gradle-plugin'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:84)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$500(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:407)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$2(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:430)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:360)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:430)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:406)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
```

I have not made any changes to the config files except the following

- /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties -> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip -> was 8.0.1
- /android/build.gradle -> classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.6') -> was 7.4.2

I am at a dead end and could use some help. Any help is appreciated. I am using gradle version 8.6-all and Java vesion 21.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgraded jdk to 17 and it worked. Not sure what it has to do with permissions but it worked